# Needs indexes to redirect to HomePage if not logged-in in Php

Tags: php, html

I am having a problem in the simple webpage I've been working for. After I uploaded it in the network,some of the files are visible like this[image]

I hope someone can help me with my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place an .htaccess file in your root web directory with this information:

```
Options -Indexes
```

This will prevent the contents of your directory from being listed. You can also place a blank index.html file in there and that would show a blank page when someone attempted to open up that directory.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to make an .htaccess file? thanks

Comment: Just create a file called `.htaccess`, place that line in it, and place it in your root web directory. That's it.